# Efficient way of checking pointer for NULL in C

Tags: c

What is the most efficient way to check if the pointer for NULLness if this check exists inside a function in a fast codepath ?

Comment: `if (ptr == NULL)`

Comment: I dont see any faster way than a `if` that is checking if the pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: `if (ptr)` looks even better to me, more efficient, since it saves typing.

Comment: @H2CO3  if(NULL==ptr)  is even a better way, isin't it??

Comment: `if (p == NULL)`, `if (p == 0)` and `if (!p)` are all going to generate the same code on any sensible compiler anyway. Choose the one you prefer the look of.

Comment: @SanyamGoel No, why would it?

Comment: @H2CO3 comparing rValue with lValue prevents unintentional assignments as it will produce compile time error if one = is missed in == operator which would have otherwise resulted in infinite loop ;)

Comment: @SanyamGoel I find `p == NULL` easier to read and I compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. I don't think Jedi comparisons serve any purpose for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable to expect the **same** efficiency

```
if (!p)
if (p == NULL)
if (p == 0)
if (NULL == p)  // Jedi comparison
if (0 == p)     // Jedi comparison
```

compile to the same code on any sensible compiler.  Credit: @Will.

Jedi comparisons do catch `=` when `==` is intended (Credit: @Sanyam Goel)
I and others find the usual `if(p == ...)` easier to read.  (Credit: @H2CO3)
Maintenance trumps development in my book.  I tend to favor `if (p == NULL)` for that reason as it express most clearly, IMHO, what is being tested.

---

Although the question is very basic, I think it deserved a complete answer.  But the kudos go to the fine discussion above.  Likely most programmers ponder this question at some point.